# Excluding FileTypes from Visual Studio Go To File Searches

Tags: visual-studio

This question is not about the Find in Files search (to clarify).
Is it possible to configure Visual Studio to confine its Go To File searches to C# files.

It is uber annoying to have the search cluttered by the thousands of client side files (svg, js, png) etc. You virtually have to type the whole name of the file, which kinda negates the usefulness of the smart filtering (e.g. using caps for the caps in the class itself, matching the casing - so `MM` for `MeetingModality.cs`).

Would love to know if such a configuration is possible. Would make my daily development life a lot easier.